# Circular dependency between the following tasks: :app:processDebugResources \--- :app:processDebugResources

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies, resources

What could be the problem?

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.CircularReferenceException: Circular dependency between the following tasks:
  :app:processDebugResources
  --- :app:processDebugResources (*)

I try to change the version of buildTools
that is my biuld.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.ban_hang'
    compileSdk 33
    buildToolsVersion "34.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ban_hang"
        minSdk 33
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation project(path: ':app')
    implementation project(path: ':app')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What you were trying to do, a little explanation about the problem would be nice

Comment: @FarkhodAbdukodirov I trying to build a RecyclerView and add some data from ArrayList to Adapter

Comment: Please update your post with your problem explanation

Answer (score 0):

Two potential reasons:

- `implementation project(path: ':app')` lines refer to the same project. (Assuming the contents above are the `:app` module's `build.gradle` contents.)
- There are two modules in your multi-module build with the same name (not sure yet why this could be a problem, but that was my problem).